# What does AutoMapper MapAtRuntime() do?

Tags: automapper

I have seen `MapAtRuntime()` function in AutoMapper, and this is the explanation that I get from intellisense:

> Do not precompute the execution plan for this member, just map it at runtime.
>   Simplifies the execution plan by not inlining.

But what does it actually do? And how/when should I use it?

```
// I don't know if this is the correct usage, and what difference does it make
CreateMap<MyEntity, MyViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MyField, opt => opt.MapAtRuntime());
```

I have not been able to find any documentation on this, just [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/Bug/MapAtRuntime/MapAtRuntime.cs):

Comment: Most likely you'll never need it. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Then set MapAtRuntime. See how the plan changes. Maybe that explanation will make more sense.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu for me it *sounds* like something I want (i.e. I need to call a method for more complicated mapping that cannot be done with an expression tree). So is that what this is for?

Comment: PS. this is the top google match for 'automapper mapatruntime' and there isn't even an answer :-(

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu You said you have answered the question https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3007, but you not. You just added a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Did you do what I said above? Because that's the answer.

Comment: If @LucianBargaoanu knew the answer, he would have provided it 2.5 years ago! This is a public forum, you don't have any obligation to answer the question... I just don't understand why you are insisting that you have answered it?

Comment: It seems to me I gave enough information for anyone willing to take the time to easily answer for themselves. That's why :)

Answer (score 2):

> But what does it actually do?

I found the following in [the official documentation under "Long compilation times"](https://docs.automapper.org/en/v12.0.1/Configuration.html#long-compilation-times):

> Compilation times increase with the size of the execution plan and that depends on the number of properties and their complexity. Ideally, you would fix your model so you have many small DTOs, each for a particular use case. But you can also decrease the size of the execution plan without changing your classes.
>
> You can set `MapAtRuntime` per member or `MaxExecutionPlanDepth` globally (the default is one, set it to zero).
>
> These will reduce the size of the execution plan by replacing the execution plan for a child object with a method call. The compilation will be faster, but the mapping itself might be slower. Search the repo for more details and use a profiler to better understand the effect. Avoiding `PreserveReferences` and `MaxDepth` also helps.

So, by using `.MapAtRuntime()`, the [execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/v12.0.1/Understanding-your-mapping.html) will not be pre-computed. Instead, it will be mapped at runtime. This simplifies the execution-plan by not using [inline mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/73ba4003e49e37e5fffec49b67e7d9ea1cbb8a8a/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MemberConfigurationExpression.cs#L22):

```cs
public void MapAtRuntime() => PropertyMapActions.Add(pm => pm.Inline = false);
```

> And how/when should I use it?

If you experience a performance-decrease with your mappings and your execution plan is very complex, you can use `MapAtRuntime()` to improve performance again. But, as mentioned above, ideally you would make your model less complex and thus improve the performance of your mapping.